# Making @XmlTransient annotation just for serializing?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, cxf, deserialization

I use Spring and Apache CXF for my project that implements java Web Services with first-code style.

I have a variable as defined:

```
@XmlTransient
public String word;
```

So that variable doesn't map to an attribute at XML.

However I want it to be ignored to mapping XML element at serialization but not at deserialization.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that with `@XmlTransient`. An option would be to use [MOXy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML) to marshal using one schema and unmarshal using another schema. You can find a great example [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html).

A simple but less elegant workaround would be something like this:

```
@XmlTransient
public String word;

public void setDeserializedWord(String word) {
   this.word = word;
}

@XmlElement(name="word")
public String getDeserializedWord() {
   return null;
}
```

Comment: +1 for MOXy.  MOXy's `@XmlReadOnly` annotation would also work for this use case.

Comment: My application uses Hibernate and some other libraries. Does using Moxy or any other libraries make conflicts with the libraries that uses serializing and deserializing?